# Table View not showing detail view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, detailview

I've implemented [this tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/12/ios-programming-recipe-16-2-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web-ios-7-and-afnetworking-2-0/) into my project but instead of showing the arrow on the right hand side and clicking through to the detailview, the table takes up the whole view (even over the status bar) and does not show the arrows or push through. Is it because of the tab bar I used? I put this in programmatically in the appdelegate file.

**my tableviewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self makeRestuarantRequests];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)makeRestuarantRequests
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restuarants+in+greenwich&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyD-kWneJACswSQfMFQ7sxRPhAEZpHHgvnw"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id     responseObject) {

    self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];

    NSLog(@"The Array: %@",self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking);

    [self.tableView reloadData];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

}];

[operation start];

}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"rating"] != NULL)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",[tempDictionary   objectForKey:@"rating"]];
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
}

return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Prepare For Segue

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
ViewController *detailViewController = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
detailViewController.restaurantDetail = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

@end
```

**my appdelegate file (tab bar stuff)**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//Add tab bar
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

//Specify viewcontrollers for each tab
MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
TableViewController *evc = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
AboutViewController *avc = [[AboutViewController alloc]init];

//Label for tabs
[mvc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Map"];
[evc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Eat"];
[avc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"About"];

[mvc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"103-map.png"]];
[evc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"125-food.png"]];
[avc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"28-star.png"]];

[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:mvc, evc, avc, nil]];


//Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window setRootViewController:tbc]; //tab bars

return YES;
}
```

[image: This is the view I get. It still scrolls etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to nsuinteger's answer, the problem with the table cell's `detailLabel` is that you're not specifying the correct *style* of table view cell:

```
// default style
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

You want `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` styled cells and you probably also want to set the `accessoryType` property, too, for the disclosure indicator:

```
// subtitle style
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Comment: This helped with my style, thank you! However it still doesn't push through to my detailView. I've checked all the connections too

Comment: The push through to the detail view probably has something to do with your segue, which should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

2 things.

1. your didFinishLoadingWithOptions method seems weird. where is the view controller you add into the self.Window ? this line >> `[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];`  if you're using storyboards I dont understand why you do this on appdelegate...
2. For tableview overlapping with top bars use this to avoid it

   viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

your didFinishLoadingWithOptions should look like this for self.Window part

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window setRootViewController:tbc]; //tab bars
```

Comment: do I put `viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` in viewDidLoad? And do I change the viewController part because xCode does not like it!